# App crashes when adding contacts to group

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook

I have an array of contacts, when I am trying to add a contact into a group, its crash my application. Here is my code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < [contactArray count]; i++)
{
    ABRecordRef newPerson =  [contactArray objectAtIndex:i];
    ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty,name, &error);
    ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phone,nil);
    ABAddressBookAddRecord(iPhoneAddressBook, newPerson, &error);
    ABAddressBookSave(iPhoneAddressBook, &error);

    BOOL add = ABGroupAddMember(newGroup, newPerson, &error);
    if (add) {
        NSLog(@"added");
    }
}
```

My application crashes on `ABRecordRef newPerson = [contactArray objectAtIndex:i];`

How can I get the record of a person from the array to add it to a group ?

Comment: Please provide the error displayed on the console

Comment: In  which os its crash? In ios 6  you get permission access  use address book contact

Comment: @Bigood There is no any error log on console I just got EXC_BAD_ACCESS on that line.

Comment: @Nims Yes, Its crash on ios 6 I have already checked for permission in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ABRecordRef newPerson = (id)[contactArray objectAtIndex:i];
```

A `ABRecordRef` is a `typedef` for `CFTypeRef` and that in turn resolves to `const void *`.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code and try:

```
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef);

    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBookRef);
for (int i=0;i < nPeople;i++) {
 ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople,i);


        NSString *firstName, *lastName;
        ABMultiValueRef phones;
        firstName =(__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
        lastName  = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty));
        phones = (ABMultiValueRef)ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
 }
    CFRelease(allPeople);
```

Comment: Hey its work ,but I want to add in group only selected contacts from array. it is possible with this?

Comment: No, ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople will give all peoples in address book..For selection you use ABPeoplePickerNavigationController